# opam switch install in foreign chroot picks version for host architecture, not guest architecture

Tags: ocaml, opam

I am trying to set up OCaml on a bunch of systems, each with a different processor architecture. OS is Debian buster.

**Edit: Architectures other than amd64 are foreign chroot environments on an amd64 host.**

**Edit 2: The goal is to build for any architecture on demand, just by supplying the target architecture as an argument. Therefore, toolchains should be as uniform as possible – regardless of whether they are 32 or 64-bit, or whether host and guest srchitecture are related.**

From the install script:

```
opam init -y --disable-sandboxing
eval $(opam config env)
# switches are named after the OCaml version
opam switch create $OCAML_VERSION $OCAML_VERSION -y
```

I have tried this with OCaml version 4.14.1. This works on armhf as well as on amd64, but on i386 I get the following error:

```
#=== ERROR while compiling ocaml-base-compiler.4.14.1 =========================#
# context              2.0.3 | linux/x86_64 |  | https://opam.ocaml.org#6830df55
# path                 ~/.opam/4.14.1/.opam-switch/build/ocaml-base-compiler.4.14.1
# command              /usr/bin/make -j1
# exit-code            2
# env-file             ~/.opam/log/ocaml-base-compiler-13962-b76d46.env
# output-file          ~/.opam/log/ocaml-base-compiler-13962-b76d46.out
### output ###
# signals_osdep.h:33:57: error: ‘REG_R15’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘REG_SS’?
# [...]
#                                                          ^~~~~~~
# signals_nat.c:228:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘CONTEXT_YOUNG_PTR’
#      Caml_state->young_ptr = (value *) CONTEXT_YOUNG_PTR;
#                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I get the same error on 4.14.0 and 4.08.1; 4.13.1 and 4.12.1 throw an error for a different identifier (`REG_RIP`) in the same file. At least one of these versions works, however, on arm64, armhf, ppc64el and s390x (all in foreign chroots).

<del>According to https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/11904, 32-bit support for OCaml is being pulled, but that goes for both arm and x86 (while armhf still seems to work), and I’m not sure what the first 64-bit-ony version is (5.x is mentioned) – all the way back from 4.14.x to 4.08.x seems a bit long.</del>

**Edit:** As pointed out in comments, I see that opam is mis-identifying the system as x86_64. Around line 21 of the output file I see:

```
echo '#define HOST "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"' >> build_config.h
```

but no indication how this was obtained. The value is identical to `$MACHTYPE` on the host system, but `$MACHTYPE` on the chroot reports `i686-pc-linux-gnu`. Foreign chroots for other platforms do not seem to have this issue.

Why does opam think it is running on a 64-bit platform, and how can I force it to install the 32-bit version?

Comment: This is a configuration error, your system is not detected as a 32bit OS but as an amd64 target. What is the output of `./configure`? (which is stored in the opam out file). 32bit support is not pulled out: it is not added back to OCaml 5.

Comment: Indeed, didn’t notice this at first. I need to reproduce this (this is from a CI environment, and output from that run is no longer available) – what should I look for in `./configure` output?

Comment: The detected build/host/target would be a good start.

Comment: Apparently this has to do with the fact that, apart from amd64, all archs are provided as a foreign chroot on an amd64 host; I’ve updated the question to reflect that. Apparently `qemu-i386-static` on amd64 cuts some corners (being just a 32-bit flavor of the host), causing the host architecture to be leaked into the chroot, which does not happen if host and guest are completely different architectures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the issue is that the host architecture is being leaked, the easiest workaround might be to explicit request a 32bit compiler with `ocaml-option-32bit` option:

```bash
opam switch create 4.14.1+32bit ocaml-variants.4.14.1+options ocaml-option-32bit
```

EDIT: With older version of opam (<2.1?) the CLI invocation is

```
opam switch create 4.14.1+32bit --packages=ocaml-variants.4.14.1+options,ocaml-option-32bit
```

Comment: I’łl try that. It will require some special handling when building for i386, though. Would the same work for building arm32 code on arm64? In that case, this approach could save me the overhead of another foreign chroot.

Comment: Unfortunately, on Debian buster, this fails with `opam: PACKAGES... arguments: Invalid character in package name "4.14.1+32bit"`. Changing the plus sign for something else did not help.

Comment: That was the wrong command: one needs to install a switch rather than a package. This is now fixed. I don't know how well tested is the arm64 + 32-bit compatibility mode.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04 (opam 2.1.2), but on debian buster (opam 2.0.3) I get `[ERROR] Invalid extra arguments ocaml-variants.4.14.1+options ocaml-option-32bit`. Although `opam switch create 4.14.1 4.14.1 -y` works, no idea why it is fussing about extra arguments.

Comment: Ah yes, opam 2.0 requires a slightly different invocation.